# NoClassDefFoundError Html.fromHtml android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, fromhtml

My code was working fine a day ago but now my application crashes with particular error when I try to use to populate html text inside my `TextView` i am using android JellyBean 4.4

> Exception: **E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android/text/Html$HtmlParser**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            holder.desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
            holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(title, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));

        } else {
            //this is where i am getting exception
            holder.desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));
            holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this create a method like below code

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String data){
    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       result = Html.fromHtml(data,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
       result = Html.fromHtml(data);
    }
    return result;
}
```

than use this way

```
holder.desc.setText(fromHtml(desc));
holder.title.setText(fromHtml(title));
```